# Photoshop blending mode to OpenGL ES without shaders

Tags: opengl-es, photoshop

I need to imitate Photoshop blending modes ("multiply", "screen" etc.) in my OpenGL ES 1.1 code (**without** shaders).

There are some docs on how to do this **with** HLSL:

- [http://www.nathanm.com/photoshop-blending-math/ (archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20090222030436/http://nathanm.com/photoshop-blending-math)
- http://mouaif.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/photoshop-math-with-glsl-shaders/

I need at least working Screen mode.

Are there any implementations on fixed pipeline I may look at?

Comment: [This](http://www.pegtop.net/delphi/articles/blendmodes/) page has _a lot_ of detail on how each blend mode works (with diagrams)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most photoshop blend-modes are based upon the Porter-Duff blendmodes.

These requires that all your images (textures, renderbuffer) are in premultiplied color-space. This is usually done by multiplying all pixel-values with the alpha-value before storing them in a texture. E.g. a full transparent pixel will look like black in non-premultiplied color space. If you're unfamiliar with this color-space spend an hour or two reading about it on the web. It's a neat and good concept and required for photoshop-like compositions.

Anyway - once you have your images in that format you can enable SCREEN using:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR)
```

The full MULTIPLY mode is not possible with the OpenGL|ES pipeline. If you only work with full opaque pixels you can fake it using:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_SRC_COLOR)
```

The results for transparent pixels either in your texture and your framebuffer will be wrong though.

Answer (score 11):

you should try this:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

This looks like multiplying to me on the iPhone / OpenGL ES

Comment: Thank you for great answer, looks exactly like multiply in photoshop (:

Comment: This only works if the image is a solid color (opaque).  If you have an image with transparency you simply need to put it in front of a white background and then try this.

Answer (score 1):

Your best place to start is to pick up a copy of the [Red Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321335732) and read through the chapters on on materials and blending modes.  It has a  very comprehensive and clear explanation of how the 'classic' OpenGL blending functions work.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using this:

`glDepthFun( GL_LEQUAL);`

was all need to get a screen effect, at least it worked well on my project.

I am not sure why this works, but if someone knows please share.