# OpenGL photoshop overlay blend mode

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

Im trying to implement a particle system (using OpenGL 2.0 ES), where each particle is made up of a quad with a simple texture

[image: the red pixels are transparent]

the red pixels are transparent. Each particle will have a random alpha value from 50% to 100%

Now the tricky part is i like each particle to have a blendmode much like Photoshop "overlay" i tried many different combinations with the glBlendFunc() but without luck.

I dont understand how i could implement this in a fragment shader, since i need infomations about the current color of the fragment. So that i can calculate a new color based on the current and texture color.

I also thought about using a frame buffer object, but i guess i would need to re-render my frame-buffer-object into a texture, for each particle since each particle every frame, since i need the calculated fragment color when particles overlap each other.

Ive found math' and other infomations regrading the Overlay calculation but i have a hard time figuring out which direction i could go to implement this.

- http://www.pegtop.net/delphi/articles/blendmodes/
- [Photoshop blending mode to OpenGL ES without shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818230/photoshop-blending-mode-to-opengl-es-without-shaders)

Im hoping to have a effect like this:

[image: overlapping particles and how they blend together]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You **can** get information about the current fragment color in the framebuffer on an iOS device. Programmable blending has been available through the [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) extension since iOS 6.0 (on every device supported by that release). Just declare that extension in your fragment shader (by putting the directive `#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require` at the top) and you'll get current fragment data in `gl_LastFragData[0]`.

And then, yes, you can use that in the fragment shader to implement any blending mode you like, including all the Photoshop-style ones. Here's an example of a Difference blend:

```
// compute srcColor earlier in shader or get from varying
gl_FragColor = abs(srcColor - gl_LastFragData[0]);
```

You can also use this extension for effects that don't blend two colors. For example, you can convert an entire scene to grayscale -- render it normally, then draw a quad with a shader that reads the last fragment data and processes it:

```
mediump float luminance = dot(gl_LastFragData[0], vec4(0.30,0.59,0.11,0.0));
gl_FragColor = vec4(luminance, luminance, luminance, 1.0);
```

You can do all sorts of blending modes in GLSL without framebuffer fetch, but that requires rendering to multiple textures, then drawing a quad with a shader that blends the textures. Compared to framebuffer fetch, that's an extra draw call and a lot of schlepping pixels back and forth between shared and tile memory -- this method is a lot faster.

On top of that, there's no saying that framebuffer data has to be color... if you're using multiple render targets in OpenGL ES 3.0, you can read data from one and use it to compute data that you write to another. (Note that the extension works differently in GLSL 3.0, though. The above examples are GLSL 1.0, which you can still use in an ES3 context. See the [spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) for how to use framebuffer fetch in a `#version 300 es` shader.)

Comment: THANKS!!! i just dumped many hours of headache code with FBO switching to integrate it with gl_LastFragData, amazing so simple it was with this infomation. Thank you so much for that! it works and performs like a charm!

Comment: Well that's a new one to me. As should be evidenced by my incorrect answer below. So a general GLSL tip that may be helpful: try to avoid branches. They not only stall the pipeline but often reduce parallelisation (because they reduce the number of simultaneous things the same program counter can be used for). You probably want to work out both the lightening and darkening paths and end up effectively picking the one or the other by clamping or mixing.

Comment: Just to expand on the answer, on iOS you should add the line "#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require" in your shader to enable gl_LastFragData.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want this configuration:
Source: GL_SRC_ALPHA
Destination: GL_ONE.
Equation: GL_ADD

If not, it might be helpful if you could explain the math of the filter you're hoping to get.

Comment: setting those configuration on a 100% alpha quad with the texture mapped on it results in a 100% alpha white circle shown, the expected result would look like this (http://ge.tt/26KUDev/v/0) ive added links to similar questions / math calculations :)

Comment: looks like the file sharing service doesnt work atm, ive uploaded the expected result image again here: http://cl.ly/image/0o1p1M0R3n0b

Comment: @madsleejensen it's not the same as an overlay (I'm writing a big answer on that), but does additive blending give you anything close to what you'd like if you colour the source circle differently?

Comment: @Tommy the problem is i like the "background color" to be animating aswell, and thereby using "fixed" colours wont work. My first attempt was actually to hardcode particle colours in depending on the current background color and their position (since its a gradient background color)

Comment: @madsleejensen additive blending adds the colour from the particle to the colour of the background. Whether or not you have a fixed background colour is immaterial. If the particle colour is (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0) then the particle will lighten all three channels of the existing background image by 0.1.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: the answer below is true for OpenGL and OpenGL ES pretty much everywhere *except* iOS since 6.0. See rickster's answer for information about `EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch` which, in ES 3.0 terms, allows a target buffer to be flagged as `inout`, and introduces a corresponding built-in variable under ES 2.0. iOS 6.0 is over a year old at the time of writing so there's no particular excuse for my ignorance; I've decided not to delete the answer because it's potentially valid to those finding this question based on its opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0 and shader tags.]

To confirm briefly:

- the OpenGL blend modes are implemented in hardware and occur after the fragment shader has concluded;
- you can't programmatically specify a blend mode;
- you're right that the only workaround is to ping pong, swapping the target buffer and a source texture for each piece of geometry (so you draw from the first to the second, then back from the second to the first, etc).

Per Wikipedia and the link you provided, Photoshop's overlay mode is defined so that the output pixel from a background value of `a` and a foreground colour of `b`, `f(a, b)` is `2ab` if `a < 0.5` and `1 - 2(1 - a)(1 - b)` otherwise.

So the blend mode changes per pixel depending on the colour already in the colour buffer. And each successive draw's decision depends on the state the colour buffer was left in by the previous.

So there's no way you can avoid writing that as a ping pong.

The closest you're going to get without all that expensive buffer swapping is probably, as Sorin suggests, to try to produce something similar using purely additive blending. You could juice that a little by adding a final ping-pong stage that converts all values from their linear scale to the S-curve that you'd see if you overlaid the same colour onto itself. That should give you the big variation where multiple circles overlap.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i just find it odd that i dont have access to the current color of the render buffer inside the fragment shader, i mean shouldnt there be a way to implement what glBlendFunc does behind the scenes somehow :) ? Im new to OpenGL so i dont have a feel on performance, would you say running ~40 particles (moving randomly) on a gradient background and splitting the render steps up into 3-4 passes maybe (background, first layer particles, second layer particles ...) using FBO's would perform on a device like a iPhone or is it a way too expensive operation every 60fps?

Comment: Ive manged to implement this using a "lookup" texture (the background) when rendering the particles in the fragment shader, and then use the overlay color calculation, it needs alot of tweaking but it seems to work :)

Comment: Actually, programmable blending **is** possible... on iOS 6.0 (and later) devices. (And this question is tagged iOS, so it's fair game.)